Is it possible to use 2 "and" filters after "where" or not?
I have a task in home assignment with follow description:
The following information must be displayed: 
• Flight ID;
• Delivery airport code;
• Arrival airport code;
• Scheduled departure date and time;
• Actual departure date and time;
• How long the flight was delayed;
• Minimum departure delay time for departure at the airport;
• Average departure delay time for departure at the airport;
• Maximum departure delay time for departure at the airport;
The data must be displayed only for those flights where information about the actual departure date                     
and time exists, and the delay time is 1 minute or more.

Then I wrote query:
     select *
 ,flight_id 
 ,departure_airport
 ,arrival_airport 
 ,scheduled_departure 
 ,actual_departure
 ,avg(actual_departure - scheduled_departure)
 ,max(actual_departure - scheduled_departure)
  from booking.flights
  where actual_departure is not null
  and actual_departure != ' ' // to filtrate column "actual_departure" by fields which 
 consist of ' '
  and (actual_departure - scheduled_departure) > '1'
  group by flight_id
  ;
  

But I have noticed 1 problem - in description was told about "NOT NULL" fields in column actual departure, but I am sure that in data can be a lot of fields not with NULL but with " ".
How can I filtrate these fields too?
When I try to use second AND the DBeaver shows me error

SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with
time zone: " ".

Using " " instead of ' ' didn't help.
I can't get an info about secondary using of operator "AND" after using "WHERE" and first "AND. Need help to understanding which method I can use to filtrate column actual_departure by fields which
consist of ' '.

You can't compare a timestamp TYPE to a string literal. It's a pretty safe assumption that actual_departure column in table booking.flights is a TIMESTAMP type, therefore it can't have the value '  '. It will either hold a TIMESTAMP or it will hold NULL. Therefore you can remove and actual_departure != ' '. The reason this error pops instead of a more reasonable error like "ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > string" is because postgres is trying really hard to implictly cast that ' ' to a timestamp and failing.

The error has nothing to with AND, it's just the input that is not valid: invalid input

Also this question doesn't have anything to do with dbeaver, that's just your sql client and this error is just being bubbled up in the dbeaver UI (just like any sql client would do). Your RDBMS is much more relevant, which is why I've added Postgresql to your question tags. It's a common misconception.

Number one, talking about "and filters" makes no sense.  "And" isn't a filter, it's a logical operation that you can use to build up an expression that's used as part of the WHERE condition.  In your example, there WHERE clause is
where actual_departure is not null
  and actual_departure != ' ' 

Number two, did you read the actual error message you got?
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: " ".

Apparently the type of actual_departure is timestamp with time zone.  So it cannot be equal to a single space because that's not a value such a column can hold in the first place.

Thanks, Sir, my bad! So I can write and actual_departure::text <> ' ', right? It would be the same type of date so I can compare them.

It is often easier to maintain and read if there is a single WHERE condition for a single column: trim(coalesce(actual_departure, '')) != ''

@NersesSorokin Why do you allow invalid input into your SQL? You should validate the input before

and actual_departure::text <> ' ' is of zero utility. If actual_departure column uses data type timestamp, it can only hold a null, infinity, -infinity or an actual timestamp between midnight January 1st, 4713 BC and right before midnight on December 31st, 294276 AD. It will never hold any combination of whitespace or any other characters you'd need to worry about. Under the hood, it's an 8-byte number that only gets converted and formatted when the db shows it to you. On input it only understands non-digits thanks to masks provided via locale settings or to_date().
